# Why Postgresql ts_query remove last char?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I've run following query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (
       SELECT 
          ts_rank(document, to_tsquery('idis:*')) AS qrank,
          public.tbl_company.company_name as name,
          public.tbl_company.document as vector,
          to_tsquery('idis:*') as query
       FROM
          public.tbl_company
       WHERE
          public.tbl_company.document @@to_tsquery('idis:*')  
     UNION 
       SELECT 
          ts_rank(document, to_tsquery('idis:*')) AS qrank,
          public.tbl_person.full_name as name,
          public.tbl_person.document as vector,
          to_tsquery('idis:*') as query
       FROM
          public.tbl_person
       WHERE
          public.tbl_person.document @@to_tsquery('idis:*')
      )as customers
  ORDER BY qrank DESC
```

And I've received following result:

[image]

I've search a text as 'idis' but ts_query remove 's' char and search 'idi'. Results ordered by rank and rank of idil greather than idis.

Why ts_query removed last char?
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what's `idis`? I think it normalizes it to idi thinking idis is plural for idi

Comment: I've received another similar result. result number for 'ece kalibrasy' as 0 but result number of 'ece kalibrasyo' as 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoul set your default text search configuration to a language where the stemming rules are as you expect them to be:

```
SET default_text_search_config='english';

SELECT to_tsvector('İdil') @@ to_tsquery('idis:*');
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

SET default_text_search_config='turkish';

SELECT to_tsvector('İdil') @@ to_tsquery('idis:*');
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│ f        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```